# Adding data to cart.json file (Asynchronous call)

Tags: node.js

just started working with node js so i am having and issue.First of all i would like to show u my code.

shop.js

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()
const shopcontroller=require('../controllers/shop')

router.get('/cart',shopcontroller.getcart)
router.post('/cart',shopcontroller.postcart)

module.exports=router
```

controller/shop.js

```
const Product=require('../models/products')
const Cart=require('../models/cart')
exports.postcart=(req,res,next)=>{
const proid=req.body.productid
Product.findbyid(proid).then((product)=>{
    Cart.addproduct(proid,product.price)
})
res.redirect('/cart')
}
```

models/cart

```
const fs=require('fs')
const path=require('path')
const  p=path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
'data','carts.json')
module.exports=class Cart{
static addproduct(id,productprice){

    fs.readFile(p,(err,data)=>{
     let cart={products:[],totalPrice:0}
     if(!err){
        cart=JSON.parse(data)
        console.log('cart',cart)
     }


     const existingProductIndex = cart.products.findIndex(p => p.id 
=== id);
    console.log('existing pordcut index',existingProductIndex)
    const existingProduct = cart.products[existingProductIndex];
     console.log('existingProduct',existingProduct)
if(existingProduct) {
    existingProduct.qty += 1;
    console.log('final',existingProduct)
    console.log('-------------------')
}
else {
    cart.products.push({
        id,
        qty: 1
    });

    cart.totalPrice += Number(productprice);
    console.log('cart',cart);
    fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), error => {
    });
}
})
}
}
```

so here what i do is if the product does not exist in my cart i add it and if it exists i just increase the quantity and totalprice
but when the product already exists my code works fine but as i write into the file via

```
 fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), error => {
    });
```

so i think before the file is being read the cart is being written on the file and so the quantity does not increases in the cart
How should i manage this ?
We can see first time when my cart is empty we see this in the console

**https://ibb.co/8MHMZLc**

and for the second time when my prodcut already exist we see this in the console

**https://ibb.co/856qbW6**

the console.log(cart) gets executed first so before the qty gets increase it gets executed and m not getting the desired output cause it is being written in the file beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cart.totalPrice += Number(productprice);
console.log('cart',cart);
fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), error => {
});
```

You are writing it in else block thats y it is causing an error